# Does FeatureGate attribute causes overhead?

Tags: c#, .net-core, feature-flags

I have been implementing feature flag management with .Net 6 solution and i came across FeatureGate attribute can be used to guard API controller or an API endpoint.
I was wondering :

1. Does FeatureGate attribute use reflection in any sense.
2. If Yes then does it cause any overhead or slows down the application.

I have been using FeatureGate attribute but someone pointed out that it uses reflection internally and can cause overhead.

Comment: _"Does FeatureGate attribute use reflection in any sense."_ - ASP.NET Core itself relies heavily on reflection anyway - so I wouldn't get concerned about the cost of a single attribute.

Comment: _"If Yes then does it cause any overhead or slows down the application."_ - that depends entirely on your application; have you tried it out yourself and used your profiler to find out? If not, _why not?_

Comment: For me it works fine but I am little concerned when it goes to production where 50000 users will be accessing api(s) guarded by FeatureGate attribute.

Comment: It's open-source, see for yourself: https://github.com/microsoft/FeatureManagement-Dotnet/blob/main/src/Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore/FeatureGateAttribute.cs - the attributes use `IFeatureManagerSnapshot` which _does_ use an on-demand loaded configuration (which will be slow to first-load, yes), buti it retains a snapshot of that config in-memory for _instant_ retrieval for all subsequent requests - of course, it depends on what settings-provider you're using with it....